# Transferring songs from iTunes to iPhone

Tags: iphone, itunes, mac

I am new to iOS platform.
Recently, I have transferred around 150 songs from my mac to my iPhone, manually without syncing. But, what I see now all songs are added to recently added folder. Is there a way to categorize them  into albums?

Comment: Just to be sure, you want to put a few songs you pick in the same place (in an Album as you said) ?

Comment: @Leonardo. Thanks for reply.But I think this might take lot of time. Is there a way so that they can be automatically categorized to my iPhone? Like if 3 songs are from same album for example The Hunting party then they can be categorized into album name same. And this goes same for all other songs?

Comment: So, you want a custom sort or an Album sort?

Comment: @Leonardo I want songs to be  categorized in albums to which they belong. Album sort will work. But, how to proceed?

Comment: Alright, got ya! Posted my answer, hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Alright I got ya.

## iOS 8/ iOS 9

In order to sort your songs in your Music App on these Operating Systems, you have to:

- **Find** under the tab "**My Music**", an **arrow** pointing down next to the text "**Song**", this is a drop down menu, **tap** it.
- It will bring you to a **list** where you can select the **sorting** method, there are several options you can choose from here.
- Finally **select** the option "**Album**" in order to **sort** every song in its own **album**.

[image: Here you can find the steps to follow.]

---

## iOS 10

I'm with you, sorting songs on iOS 8/9 can be not intuitive or fast to use, but there are great news!
In the upcoming iOS 10 update (coming this fall) the whole interface of Apple Music has been redesigned.

So, now in order to do what you asked for, it will be as easy as **opening** the Music App, **tapping** the "Library" tab, and finally **tapping** on the Album option to see all your songs sorted in their Albums.
Take a look at the new **cleaner** design:

[image: iOS 10 Apple Music App]

Answer (score 0):

The album info should have been transferred over with the song files.

In My Music on your iPhone the "Recently Added" category as the top, correct?  In the middle of the screen you should see "Songs" with a small down arrow. Touch that down arrow to toggle songs, albums, artists, etc.